# .Net - How are LinkedListNode<T>'s Properties assigned to?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

According to both the documentation and metadata for .Net's `LinkedListNode<T>` class, its `List`, `Next` and `Previous` properties are get-only. However, `LinkedList<T>` somehow manages to alter these properties.

How does `LinkedList<T>` achieve this?

Is it using reflection or is it cheating by using internal setters?

Comment: It's not a "trick". It's called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: You can always look at the .net source code: [linkedlist.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thank you, I had forgotten about Microsoft making the source code available. This has revealed that there is liberal use of the `internal` access modifier. If you would like to submit an answer referencing the source code I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are [the fields of `LinkedListNode<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#604):

```
public sealed class LinkedListNode<T> {
    internal LinkedList<T> list;
    internal LinkedListNode<T> next;
    internal LinkedListNode<T> prev;
    internal T item;

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, the fields are internal, and as such they can be manipulated by the `LinkedList<T>` (or by any other class in the `System` assembly for that matter), but you can't do that from your code.

[An example](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#326):

```
private void InternalInsertNodeBefore(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    newNode.next = node;
    newNode.prev = node.prev;
    node.prev.next = newNode;
    node.prev = newNode;            
    version++;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fields `list`, `prev` and `next` in `LinkedListNode<T>` are marked with the internal access modifier. Internal types/members are accessible only to other types in the same assembly. In this case, both `LinkedListNode<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` are in the *System* assembly.

If we look at how they are actually defined:

```
public sealed class LinkedListNode<T>
{
  internal LinkedList<T> list;
  internal LinkedListNode<T> next;
  internal LinkedListNode<T> prev;
  internal T item;
  ....
}
```

Comment: The classes are in the `System` assembly, not in `mscorlib`

Answer (score -1):

One can always change data within the same class even if its get-only property

Refer to below example:

```
class Property
{
    private string _name = "_name";
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _name = "foo";
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Property prop = new Property();

        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);  // prints _name

        prop.Foo();

        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name); // prints foo
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: As shown in above code sample, LinkedList<T> class should also be resetting Next & Prev properties when its methods AddFirst, AddLast etc are called.

Comment: What you have shown is a demonstration of properties with user-defined backing fields, not how it is possible to access a class' property's backing field from a *different* class.

Comment: But the question is not about any old class, it is asking about a pair of *specific* classes.